# symfony2: remove widget attributtes

Tags: symfony, attributes

When I've created a form:

```
    $builder = $this->createFormBuilder();
    $form = $builder->add( 'add', 'button')->getForm();
```

and render it:

```
    <div><button type="button" id="form_add" name="form[add]">Add</button></div>
```

the attributes type, id and name are created.

I want to erase this attributes but I don't know how to do it. I've tried to do:

```
    $builder = $this->createFormBuilder();
    $form = $builder->add( 'add', 'button', array( 'attr' => array() ) )->getForm();
```

without any success.

How could I do it?

Greetings and thanks

Comment: Why remove these attributes? Removing the `name` attribute may give you a non-working button.

Answer (score 0):

I messed around with this for a while and the closest I could get was to have them render with empty attributes. However, that's because the project I tested with is **Symfony 2.0**, and in that version it's impossible to completely remove the attributes since `Symfony\Component\Form\FormView::$vars` is `private`.

However, in **Symfony 2.1** and later, that same property is `public` so you should be able to modify (or delete) the attributes/vars directly without being constrained by the `FormView` api.

First, create your own type to represent this "naked button"

**src/Your/Bundle/Form/NakedButtonType.php**

```
<?php

namespace Your\Bundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormView;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;

class NakedButtonType extends AbstractType
{
  /**
   * (non-PHPdoc)
   * @see Symfony\Component\Form.FormTypeInterface::getName()
   */
  public function getName()
  {
    return "naked_button";
  }

  /**
   * (non-PHPdoc)
   * @see Symfony\Component\Form.AbstractType::getParent()
   */
  public function getParent(array $options)
  {
    return 'button';
  }

  /**
   * (non-PHPdoc)
   * @see Symfony\Component\Form.AbstractType::buildViewBottomUp()
   */
  public function buildViewBottomUp(FormView $view, FormInterface $form)
  {
    // Symfony 2.0
    // This will still render the attributes, but they will have no value
    $view->set('id', null);
    $view->setAttribute('type', null);

    // Symfomy >= 2.1
    // This *should* remove them completely
    unset( $view->vars['id'] );
    unset( $view->vars['attr']['type'] );
  }
}
```

Now, tell the service container how to build your type

**app/config/config.yml**

```
services:
  form.type.naked_button:
    class: Your\Bundle\Form\NakedButtonType
    tags:
      - {name: form.type, alias: naked_button}
```

Then update your parent form to use your new type instead of the ootb "button" type.

```
$builder = $this->createFormBuilder();
$form = $builder->add( 'add', 'naked_button')->getForm();
```

***All of that being said...***

If you want these buttons w/o any attributes, why not just put them like that directly into your view?

```
<form>
  {{ form_errors(form) }}
  {{ form_rest(form) }}
  <div>
    <button>Add</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

All of this custom type nonsense seems like alot of overhead to render something you clearly don't need Symfony to manage for you.

Comment: Thank you! I thought it could be done using the setDefaultOptions but it is not posible.

Answer (score 0):

While not a good idea, I will help you load the gun and shoot yourself in the foot :-)

Create a new Resources/views/Form/fields.html.twig file, and put the following in it:

```
{% block widget_attributes %}
{% spaceless %}
    id="{{ id }}" name="{{ full_name }}"{% if read_only %} readonly="readonly"{% endif %}{% if disabled %} disabled="disabled"{% endif %}{% if required %} required="required"{% endif %}{% if max_length %} maxlength="{{ max_length }}"{% endif %}{% if pattern %} pattern="{{ pattern }}"{% endif %}
    {% for attrname, attrvalue in attr %}{% if attrname in ['placeholder', 'title'] %}{{ attrname }}="{{ attrvalue|trans({}, translation_domain) }}" {% else %}{{ attrname }}="{{ attrvalue }}" {% endif %}{% endfor %}
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock widget_attributes %}
```

If you really, really want to remove all the attributes on there, you can remove the {% for attrname ... %} line. That will remove the attributes from *all* form fields. If you add some logic, you can have it apply to just specific fields.

Next step, you need to register your fields helpers. In your app/config/config.yml file, add the following line:

```
twig:
    form:
        resources:
            - 'SomeBundle:Form:fields.html.twig'
```